# SQLAlchemy 'bulk_save_objects' vs 'add_all' underlying logic difference?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Considering following three methods of using sqlalchemy ORM to insert objects:

(1)

```
for obj in objects:
    session.add(obj)
```

(2)

```
session.add_all(objects)
```

(3)

```
session.bulk_save_objects(objects)
```

Suppose the length of `objects[]` is `50000`

- Does method (1) form and send `50000` insert SQL queries?
- Does method (2) form and send only `1` SQL query?
- Does method (3) form and send only `1` SQL query?

I know these three methods [differ a lot in speed](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow). But what are the difference regarding to **the underlying implementation details**?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[(2) is basically implemented](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L1996) as (1), and both may emit 50,000 inserts during flush, if the ORM has to fetch generated values such as primary keys. They may even emit more, if those 50,000 objects have relationships that cascade.

```
In [4]: session.add_all([Foo() for _ in range(5)])

In [5]: session.commit()
BEGIN (implicit)
INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING foo.id
{}
... (repeats 3 times)
INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING foo.id
{}
COMMIT
```

If you provide primary keys and other DB generated values beforehand, then the `Session` can combine separate inserts to a single "executemany" operation when the arguments match.

```
In [8]: session.add_all([Foo(id=i) for i in range(5)])

In [9]: session.commit()
BEGIN (implicit)
INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (%(id)s)
({'id': 0}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4})
COMMIT
```

If your DB-API driver implements [`executemany()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) or [equivalent](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-fast-execution-helpers) using a method that allows it to issue a single statement with multiple data, then it can result in a single query. For example after enabling [`executemany_mode='values'`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-executemany-mode) the Postgresql log contains for the above

```
LOG: statement: INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4)
```

The bulk operation skips most of the `Session` machinery — such as persisting related objects — in exchange for performance gains. For example by default it does not fetch default values, such as primary keys, which allows it to try and batch changes to fewer "executemany" operations where the operation and arguments match.

```
In [12]: session.bulk_save_objects([Foo() for _ in range(5)])
BEGIN (implicit)
INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES
({}, {}, {}, {}, {})

In [13]: session.commit()
COMMIT
```

It may still emit multiple statements, again depending on the data, and the DB-API driver in use. The [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects) is a good read.

With [psycopg2 fast execution helpers](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-fast-execution-helpers) enabled the above produces in the Postgresql log

```
LOG: statement: INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES;INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES;INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES;INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES;INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES
```

In other words multiple statements have been joined to a "single" statement sent to the server.

So, in the end the answer to all 3 is "it depends", which of course may seem frustrating.

Comment: Does `bulk_save_objects` only emit `1` SQL statement? Or will it automatically separate objects into batches?

Comment: It depends. It does try to collect them to fewer `executemany()` operations, as explained in its documentation, but it may emit more than 1 based on the given data – for example if there are both new and modified objects in the same collection. With that in mind the same caveats apply as before; performance of `executemany()` or equivalent depends on your DB-API in use. For example `psycopg2` implements `executemany()` as a simple loop that performs pretty poorly, but offers other fast execution methods that new versions of SQLAlchemy knows how to use.

Comment: We are talking about `sqlalchemy` here, I suppose `psycopg2` is irrelevant?

Comment: Let's say all the objects are newly inserted objects, does `bulk_save_objects` separate inserting SQLs into batches? (to avoid some data too large error when `len(objects)` becomes too big)

Comment: `psycopg2` and the other DB-API drivers are very much relevant as they are what SQLAlchemy uses for actually talking to the database. Any inherent slowness in one affects the other, and in case of `executemany()` it is the driver implementation that in the end dictates the number of statements issued.

Comment: As to batching, SQLA bulk save issues one or many **"executemany"** operations and it is up to the driver to handle those in a way that avoids possible argument limits etc.

Comment: And in case you're not familiar with Python's DB-API spec, here's the relevant part: "Modules are free to implement this method using multiple calls to the .execute() method or by using array operations to have the database process the sequence as a whole in one call." https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation and edit. Turns out our service connects to MySQL, and uses PyMySQL as the DBAPI driver (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html). So I guess the answer to my questions would be "it depends on how PyMySQL implements the underlying logic."

Comment: It looks like PyMySQL speeds up "executemany" INSERT statements: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.executemany, given some syntax restrictions: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/178. I'm fairly certain that SQLA produces "well enough" SQL for it to pick up on it, but should check to be sure.