# sqlalchemy bulk_save_objects vs add_all, and return datetime

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using: Flask, MySQL
I want to insert many records and I want to do it in a bulk to increase performance.
I understood that bulk_save_objects is a good option and it is what I need. **BUT** when I use it it doesn't return a default value for my created_at and updated_at (both datetimes).

Here is my model:

```
from database.shared_db import db
from entities.student_score import StudentScore


class StudentScoresModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students_scores'

id = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(36), primary_key=True)
student_id = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(36), db.ForeignKey('students.id'), nullable=False)
attribute_id = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(36), db.ForeignKey('attributes.id'), nullable=False)
score = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
updated_at = db.Column(
    db.DateTime, 
    server_default=db.func.now(), 
    onupdate=db.func.now(), 
    nullable=False,
)
created_at = db.Column(
    db.DateTime, 
    server_default=db.func.now(), 
    nullable=False,
)

def convert_to_entity(self) -> StudentScore:
    return StudentScore(
        id=self.id,
        student_id=self.student_id,
        attribute_id=self.attribute_id,
        score=self.score,
        updated_at=self.updated_at,
        created_at=self.created_at,
    )
```

My DB method:

```
@staticmethod
def create_student_scores(
    student_scores: list[StudentScore],
) -> list[StudentScore]:
    student_scores_model: list[StudentScoresModel] = [
        StudentScoresModel(
            id=str(uuid.uuid4()),                                                                             
            attribute_id=student_Score.attribute_id,                                                                             
            score=student_Score.score,                                                                             
            student_id=student_Score.student_id
        ) for student_Score in student_scores
    ]
    db.session.bulk_save_objects(
        student_scores_model, 
        return_defaults=True,
    )
    db.session.commit()
    return [
       student_score.convert_to_entity() 
       for student_score in student_scores_model
    ]
```

The code executes alright but every StudentScore has created_at=null and updated_at=null because I assume bulk_save_objects doesn't return the generated values for these fields.

Also I thought of using add_all() but I could not understand is it suits me well. I understood that it is less efficient for performance.

Comment: maybe this will be helpfull https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-bulk-insert-statements

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517821/18734356 to understand the difference between bulk_save_objects and add_all()

Comment: In the explanation in the link you would see that bulk_save_objects does not bother fetching default values so I would say add_all() is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

try with `db.session.add()`

```
student_scores: list[StudentScoresModel] = [
    StudentScoresModel(
        id=str(uuid.uuid4()),                                                                             
        attribute_id=student_Score.attribute_id,                                                                             
        score=student_Score.score,                                                                             
        student_id=student_Score.student_id
    ) for student_Score in student_scores
]
for obj in student_scores:
    db.session.add(obj)   
db.session.bulk_save_objects(
    student_scores, 
    return_defaults=True,
)
```

Comment: But using add() impacts the performance, no?
In the same way I can do add_all() and then again I have the question of the difference between add_all and bulk_save_objects

Comment: add() means that you want to receive orm object for row, data will go to db on commit().  If you want to deal with state connected to db (modified on save in database)  you can deal wirth add() ao with separate select() query for result

Answer (score 0):

[Ryabchenko Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6515755/ryabchenko-alexander) pointed you in the right direction with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77906168/sqlalchemy-bulk-save-objects-vs-add-all-and-return-datetime#comment137355954_77906168). The modern (SQLAlchemy 2.x) solution is to execute an insert construct with a list or parameter dictionaries, like this:

```py
session.execute(insert(SomeOrmModel), [{...}, ...])
```

In this particular case we also want to return the created model instances to get the values created on the database side. Doing this using `insert` is more efficient than `bulk_save_objects(..., return_defaults=True)`, which will [execute individual insert statements for each row](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_save_objects.params.return_defaults).

Assuming some function `to_dict` which converts `StudentScore` instances to a dictionary, the solution would look like this:

```py
@staticmethod
def create_student_scores(
    student_scores: list[StudentScore],
) -> list[StudentScore]:
    student_scores_model: list[StudentScoresModel] = db.session.scalars(
        db.insert(StudentScoresModel).returning(StudentScoresModel),
        [to_dict(sscore) for sscore in student_scores],
    )
    db.session.commit()
    return [student_score.convert_to_entity() for student_score in student_scores_model]
```